# jquery sortable selector issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm having an Unordered List (see below):

[image]

my current code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("ul.tree").sortable({
            items : "li.insert"
      });
});
```

I only want the yellow elements selectable (li.insert) which works so far, but I can't move any of them above the white item ("unterbau darling new gatto") .. seems like it's only movable within li.insert elements.
Any ideas if I'm missing something?
Thanks

Comment: Provide a working example (with the html structure and everything).

Comment: When you set the `item` option as you have, that is the expected behavior. Please provide a proper example or jsfiddle.